# Python script in notepad++ for replace with a increment number

Tags: python, replace

I try to do a python script in notepad++ to replace a simbol with the same symbol + increment number, like a list

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
search_string = '▶️ '
final_str = '.-'
i = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\temp\\prueba'):  # take care of double backslash like c:\\temp\\dir1\\
    for file in files:
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if ext == '.txt':
            i+=1
            full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            with open(full_path) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(search_string, search_string + str(i) + final_str)
            with open(full_path, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
```

It doesnt work fine, it replace text with ▶️ 1.- in all coincidences but not increment the number.

How can i solve this?

one mate of here says that i only increment number each file but i need to increment number each line that have coincidence and reset each file.

Thank you very much.

Best Regards.

Comment: You only increment `i` once in each file

Comment: oh, i need increment 1 per line and reset in each file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to modify your code as follow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
search_string = '▶️ '
final_str = '.-'
i = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\temp\\prueba'):
    for file in files:
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if ext == '.txt':
            i = 0
            full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            with open(full_path, encoding="utf8") as f:
                s = f.read()

            pos = 0
            new_s = ""
            while pos >=0:
                i += 1
                # search first occurrence of '▶️ '
                pos = s.find(search_string)
                if pos >= 0:
                    # '▶️ ' found in position pos
                    s_modified = s[:pos + 3]
                    # remove analyzed string
                    s = s[pos+3:]
                    # substitute with new '▶️ 1-.' or '▶️ 2-.' etc.
                    s_modified = s_modified.replace(search_string, search_string + str(i) + final_str, 1)
                    new_s += s_modified
                else:
                    new_s += s

            with open(full_path, "w") as f:
                f.write(new_s)
```

I hope it is useful.

With the file at [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/hyoe3d6f/1/) the output is the following file:

```
¿Como encontrar uma pessoa pela foto nas redes sociais?

<b>¿Como encontrar uma pessoa pela foto nas redes sociais?. </b> <b>Outra alternativa para achar uma pessoa pela foto no Facebook é usando o Google Imagens.</b> O buscador permite fazer uma busca reversa a partir da imagem da pessoa que você está procurando. Depois de buscar, a plataforma então mostra resultados semelhantes, o que pode incluir os perfis de redes sociais da pessoa.

<h2>Melhores respostas: ¿Como encontrar uma pessoa pela foto nas redes sociais?</h2>

▶️ 1.-¿Como achar uma pessoa pela foto pelo celular? <b>Acesse o.</b> Google. e, no canto direito do campo de busca, toque no ícone de câmera;. Com isso, você acessará o. Google. Lens. Por fim, basta aguardar o processamento e explorar os resultados que aparecerão na página.

▶️ 2.-¿Como faço para encontrar uma pessoa no Google pela foto? <b>Com o.</b> Google Fotos. (Android l iOS) aberto, localize a imagem da. pessoa. ;. Deslize a página para cima e, na seção “Pesquisar dentro desta. foto. ”, clique no comando “Pesquisar”;. Os resultados aparecerão logo em seguida.

▶️ 3.-¿Como eu faço para encontrar uma pessoa? <b>Rastreie a pessoa através das redes sociais.</b> Páginas como Facebook, Instagram e Twitter permitem que você procure pelos membros com base em nome, localização, locais frequentados ou interesses. Digite o nome completo da pessoa e a última cidade conhecida dela na barra de busca da rede preferida.

▶️ 4.-¿Como encontrar uma pessoa que eu não sei o nome? <b>Utilize sites de redes sociais.</b> Sites como MySpace e Facebook oferecem várias maneiras de encontrar pessoas sem saber um sobrenome. Quando encontrar a pessoa, poderá contatá-la através do site e trocar números de telefone ou marcar um encontro.

▶️ 5.-¿Quem é a pessoa da foto? <b>Veja abaixo como encontrar uma pessoa só pela foto usando o TinEye: Abra o navegador e acesse tineye.</b>com; Insira o link da imagem ou clique em "Envio" para fazer o upload; Aguarde para que o site mostre as imagens correspondentes e outras informações.

▶️ 6.-¿Como saber o Instagram de uma pessoa? <b>Como nós já mencionamos anteriormente, a maneira mais fácil de encontrar pessoas no Instagram é sabendo seu nome de usuário.</b> Assim, basta digitar no campo de busca do app. Caso você não tenha como saber esse detalhe, é sempre possível procurar pelo nome da pessoa.

▶️ 7.-¿Como encontrar uma pessoa por foto no Facebook? <b>Outra alternativa para achar uma pessoa pela foto no Facebook é usando o Google Imagens.</b> O buscador permite fazer uma busca reversa a partir da imagem da pessoa que você está procurando. Depois de buscar, a plataforma então mostra resultados semelhantes, o que pode incluir os perfis de redes sociais da pessoa.

▶️ 8.-¿Como saber todas as redes sociais de uma pessoa? <b>Pipl.</b>com: busca a "pegada" online de um indivíduo e pode identificar várias contas de redes sociais, registros públicos e informações de contato. Rapportive: esse plug-in para o Gmail oferece aos usuários um perfil dos seus contatos, incluindo contas em redes sociais, localização e emprego.

▶️ 9.-¿Como saber todos os dados de uma pessoa? <b>Ferramentas de busca como o Google ou o Bing são excelentes opções para pesquisar o que quiser de graça.</b> Faça uma pesquisa simples incluindo o nome da pessoa e a cidade e/ou estado em que ela morava ou onde você a viu pela última vez. Não exagere nos termos de busca. Coloque aspas em volta do nome que está pesquisando.

▶️ 10.-¿Como descobrir o WhatsApp de uma pessoa só pelo nome? <b>O AcheCerto é um site, onde você pode consultar o telefone de alguém a partir do nome, endereço ou CEP.</b> Também é possível encontrar telefone pelo nome completo. O serviço está disponível para todos os estados brasileiros.

▶️ 11.-¿Como eu faço para encontrar uma pessoa pela internet? <b>Namechk.</b> Caso você tenha o nome de usuário de alguma rede social (ex.: Youtube, Twitter, Instagram, entre outros) da. pessoa. que você busca, o Namechk pode ajudar a encontrá-la. Findface. Busca reversa de imagem - Google.

▶️ 12.-¿Como localizar uma pessoa grátis? <b>Free Phone Tracker.</b> Este é um site gratuito para saber a localização de alguém pelo telefone. GPS Rastreador de celular. O aplicativo GPS Rastreador de celular é gratuito e está disponível nas lojas da Google Play e Apple Store para Android e iPhone. wSpy Pro.

▶️ 13.-¿Como fazer para encontrar uma pessoa no Facebook? <b>Toque em no canto superior direito do.</b> Facebook. . Insira o nome do seu amigo na barra de pesquisa e toque em ou em no canto inferior direito. Toque em. PESSOAS. na parte superior. Toque para filtrar por Cidade, Educação, Trabalho ou Amigos de amigos.

▶️ 14.-¿Como encontrar uma pessoa que não tem rede social? <b>Quando parecer que alguém não tenha perfil nas redes sociais, procure direito — Google, Facebook, Tumblr e LinkedIn são apenas alguns exemplos de onde procurar.</b>

▶️ 15.-¿Como pesquisar sobre a vida de uma pessoa no Google? <b>Digite o nome de quem procura na caixa de pesquisa do Google.</b> Coloque o nome de quem deseja procurar entre aspas ( ” ” ), Dessa forma o Google procura os termos exatamente como estão digitados entre as aspas. Refina sua busca e selecione as opções de sua localização e da página.

▶️ 16.-¿Como saber se a foto de uma pessoa é fake? <b>Baixe e instale o aplicativo.</b> Fake. Image Detector nas lojas de aplicativos do Chrome ou Firefox. Abra o aplicativo e selecione uma das duas opções: Escolha na galeria - Isso permite o acesso às imagens salvas em seu celular.

▶️ 17.-¿Como se chama a foto do rosto? <b>Em retrato, este é o plano em que o corpo aparece por inteiro, dos pés à cabeça.</b> O protagonista da foto ocupa, portanto, todo o enquadramento da foto, sendo o ponto de interesse da captura. A fotografia pode mostrar a pessoa mais longe ou mais perto, mas sem cortar os pés ou a cabeça.

▶️ 18.-¿Quem tirou a foto? <b>A fotografia tirada pelo francês Joseph Nicéphore Niépce (1765 – 1833), em 1826, é considerada a primeira da história.</b> Para obter esse resultado, o inventor posicionou uma folha de estanho coberta de betume durante oito horas seguidas na frente de uma janela.

▶️ 19.-¿Como achar o Instagram de uma pessoa pela foto no celular? <b>Acesse images.</b>google.com.br usando o navegador de internet. Você verá o campo de busca do Google. Clique no botão de câmera do lado direito do campo de busca. Ele vai permitir a pesquisa por imagem.

▶️ 20.-¿Como achar uma pessoa no Instagram pelo número do celular 2022? <b>Como achar alguém no instagram pelo número Toque nos três traços do canto superior lado direito.</b> Em seguida, vá em “Configurações“. Vá em “Conta” e em seguida na opção “Sincronização de contatos“. Marque a opção “Conectar contatos“.

▶️ 21.-¿Como ver o Instagram de uma pessoa pelo Google? <b>Por exemplo, caso esteja procurando o.</b> Instagram. da Beyonce, pesquise por ″. Instagram. oficial da Beyonce″. Clique no link fornecido. pela. pesquisa para acessar o perfil da. pessoa. procurada.

▶️ 22.-¿Como achar um contato do Whatsapp no Instagram? <b>Uma vez que você tenha o número da pessoa que deseja encontrar salvo, o aplicativo irá sincronizar seus contatos, permitindo que você localize um usuário através do número de celular dele.</b> Sem o número do celular da pessoa salvo, não é possível localizar o perfil dela no Instagram.

▶️ 23.-¿Como encontrar uma pessoa apenas com o primeiro nome? <b>Comece a sua busca online em um site de pesquisa de pessoas.</b> Muitos pedem o primeiro nome e o sobrenome, mas alguns, como o People Lookup, permitem que você procure apenas pelo primeiro e por uma localização. Se você não sabe onde ela mora, use o local onde a conheceu.

▶️ 24.-¿Como achar uma foto no Instagram? <b>Toque em na parte inferior para acessar.</b> Pesquisar. e Explorar. Na barra de. pesquisa. na parte superior, toque em. Pesquisar. . Digite o nome da localização e toque no botão de. pesquisa. no canto inferior direito do teclado.
```

Comment: thank you, bit i try this and dont replace anything. I give you an example of txt file in the html code of this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/hyoe3d6f/1/

Comment: i dont understand it. I have this code in the script. https://imgur.com/Rwhqrsm and this is my folder in the exactly site. https://imgur.com/qAX5Knb but when i try to execute the script in plugins->python... console not show nothing but files its same that before execute. https://imgur.com/mTIfqxt. i have notepad++ 8.4.6 x64 and python script 2.0. Thank you very much.

Comment: i've installed it. Version 3.10 and when i try to execute the .py file: https://imgur.com/tYNcoBZ. Tahnk you very much, and im so sorry for that.

Comment: Try with this type of open file `with open(full_path, encoding="utf8") as f:` that replace `with open(full_path) as f:`

Comment: now i try this, but it erase de txt files to white.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?